# Dozer mapping description to code

Tags: dozer

I am using Dozer to map my JAXB objects that come off a WebService interface to my domain objects.  One of the elements or properties in my JAXB is a **String set/setLocation()**.  This would be the description of the location.  What I need in the backend is the to take that String and map it to a code which will be stored in my database.  I've looked in the Dozer website and junit tests and I don't see anything that I can use as an example.   I was hoping I could create some custom setter mapper to do this but I am looking for an example that I can start with.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

With a little investigation I found a way to resolve my problem with a field level converter.
Here is the Dozer documentation for those interested: http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/customconverter.html